# Nested For Loops that result in no output

Tags: function-construction, iterators

I am sure that this is not the most elegant code you will have seen, but I am trying to loop through an expression to see if `FultonHarrisn]` produces any outputs that are equal to a prime squared.

My function `FultonHarris` is defined as follows:

```
FultonHarris[n_] := Product[(Sum[a[k], {k, i, j - 1}] + j - i)/(j - i), {j, 1, n}, {i, 1,
j - 1}]
```

and my for loop runs as follows, looping through `n` from `3` to `9`, and `j` from `1` to `n`, and `i` from `1` to `j-1`:

```
numPoints = 10; For[n = 3, n < 10, n++,
 For[j = 1, j <= n, j++,
  For[i = 1, i < j, i++,
     a[i] := x; a[j] := y;  a[k_] /; k != {i, j} := 0;  
   dd[x_, y_, p_] := FultonHarris[n] - p^2; 
   FindInstance[
    dd[xx, yy, pp] == 0 && xx > 0 && yy > 0 && PrimeQ[pp], {xx, yy, 
     pp}, Integers, numPoints]
   ]
  ]
 ]
```

However, when I run this, it doesn't return anything, not even empty braces. Do I need to put a `Print` statement in there?

Comment: [`For`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/For.html), [`Do`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Do.html), and [`While`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/While.html) do not return anything, try `Table`, instead.

Comment: As @rcollyer suggests, this looks like a job for Table.  But I suggest you simplify your example by making certain that each level of the iterations run properly starting from the innermost construct.  Also look at Module[], it might help you deal in a clearer way with the functions you define in each level of iteration.

Comment: what do you intend "xx", "yy",and "pp" to represent.  You don't appear to define them.

Comment: @Jagra they're parameters for [`FindInstance`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FindInstance.html).

Comment: First of all, thanks everyone for the time you took to help me out. Secondly, @Jagra, I'm not sure what you mean by "simplify your example by making certain that each level of the iterations run properly starting from the innermost construct." Do you mean setting `a[i] := x` in the beginning of the `i` loop, and setting `a[j] := y` in the beginning of the `j` loop? Regards